# Appolo-graphql client reject Base64 string data

Tags: graphql, base64, apollo-client, apollo-server

I have created a graphql endpoint using an apollo-server. But I can't include base64 image string in the payload. it causes JSON error

```
mutation {
      createMyData(input:
      {
          firstName:"test"
          lastName:"test123",
          userImage : "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABWSgIaFFiAIFEkAf//Z" (sample base64 string)
      })
      {
        firstName
      }
    }
```

I got error from playground like this

```
{
  "error": "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"
}

PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
```

Comment: Your server is returning a response with something other than JSON -- most likely HTML. Please review the actual response from the server in your browser's dev tools.

Comment: added actual error return from server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can customize the JSON packet size easily.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'}));
```